# Call class method inside the Linq Query

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method called GetAge(DateTime birthDay). I want to use this method in the Linq Query by passing the birthday and based on the returned age value need to perfrom some logic.

I want below query in LINQ format -

```
  from customer in contetx.Customer where 
  if GetAge(customer.BirthDate) > 20 and customer.accountType="Savings"
  or
  if(GetAge(customer.BirthDate) > 40 and customer.AccountType="Current"
```

Immediate help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This is Linq to entities. I am using the Entity Framework.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
context.Customer
       .AsEnumerable()  // because the method has no translation to SQL
       .Where(customer => (GetAge(customer.BirthDate) > 20 && customer.AccountType == "Savings")
                       || (GetAge(customer.BirthDate) > 40 && customer.AccountType == "Current"));
```

The `.AsEnumerable` is required if you're attempting to query an SQL database as the GetAge method in your code will have no translation to SQL. In that case the call to `.AsEnumerable` retrieves the results of the query up to that point and you're then working with local objects on which your method can operate.

If you don't want to retrieve all the results at that point because the number of records is large you could always replicate the logic from the method you want to call in your query (I'm guessing at the logic here):

```
context.Customer.Select(c => new { Customer = c, Age = (DateTime.Today.Year - c.BirthDate.Year) }
                .Where(c => (c.Age > 20 && c.Customer.AccountType == "Savings")
                         || (c.Age > 40 && c.Customer.AccountType == "Current"))
                .Select(c => c.Customer);
```

Because the operations are all available in SQL this will work.

If the method you're trying to call is particularly complex you can always move it to an extension method that takes an `IQueryable` and returns an `IQueryable`. The contents of the method will still need to have a valid translation to SQL but it will help hide more complicated logic.

For example the above query could be made to look like this:

```
context.Customers.WhoAreValidByAge();
```

Where `WhoAreValidByAge` is defined as:

```
public static IQueryable<Customer> WhoAreValidByAge(this IQueryable<Customer> customers)
{
    cusomters.Select(c => new { Customer = c, Age = (DateTime.Today.Year - c.BirthDate.Year) }
             .Where(c => (c.Age > 20 && c.Customer.AccountType == "Savings")
                      || (c.Age > 40 && c.Customer.AccountType == "Current"))
             .Select(c => c.Customer)
}
```

If the logic contained in your method doesn't translate to SQL for some reason though you have no choice but to convert the results set to LinqToObjects. In that case I'd suggest filtering the results as much as possible in SQL before calling `AsEnumerable`.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to call `AsEnumerable()`.

Comment: He's operating direct on the context using a method that, as far as I know given the information in the question, has no direct translation to Sql. If he doesn't convert to LinqToObjects (using .AsEnumable() or .ToList()) then attempting to access the information returned by the query will throw a NotSupportedException with the message Method 'GetAge' has no supported translation to SQL...

Comment: right Calling AsEnumerable may unnecessarily retrieve all the data at that point of time in query from database.

Comment: Yes, it will, but that's unavoidable if you're using a method that exists only in your code. When you try and run the other queries you'll get an exception if you try and use a method that can't be converted to SQL.

Comment: Yeah you are right i am getting the wrror u mentioned if i do not use the AsEnumerable()..But i cannt use AsEnumerable at that point as database has 2 lakhs of such customers..It will kill my app..Please suggest if you are aware of any other way.. Do u think the let keywork will work here as pointed by Darin in first answer??

Comment: No, because the problem is the method you're calling only exists in your code, the database just doesn't know what it is... I'll update my answer with a possible alternative

Comment: Thanks dave for quick response.. Just to add I am using Entity Framework and MySQl as database.

Comment: This is excelllent Dave, but GetAge is just example i gave, I have a method which does lot more which i guess can not be possible to include all in LINQ... But this idea is really gr8..

Comment: I've added another option: using extension methods. Provided they operate on IQueryable types the fact that it's a method call will be ignore and the contents will be evaluated into the SQL equivalent. The contents will still need to be valid SQL but you may be able to hide otherwise complicated subqueries.

Comment: Thanks a lot again Dave, this is right direction.. I will try it and will update the thread accordingly..

Answer (score 12):

```
var customers = from customer in contetx.Customer 
                let age = GetAge(customer.BirthDate)
                where (age > 20 && customer.accountType == "Savings") ||
                      (age > 40 && customer.accountType == "Current")
                select customer;
```

Comment: Yes, it avoids recalculating the age twice.

Comment: heyy this is great... I dont know 'let' keyword.. Darin u r champ... Thanks a lot saved lot of my time...

Comment: Darin one question.. Below Dave pointed that "because the problem is the method you're calling only exists in your code, the database just doesn't know what it is" , it may throw exception.. Do you think in this case let keyword wud work.. I will try it and update the post.. But just thought of checking with you, if you have any inputs...

Comment: Hi Darin, I tried this way but get exception as below -              LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 GetAge(System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: This will work, but filtering will be done on the client side, meaning ALL customers will be retrieved from the database. I'd suggest implementing GetAge on the server in some way, say, a calculated column or something.

Comment: I would like to know the scenario where "let" keyword would work. Below query never works- 
var query from customer in // ... 
    let age = GetAge(customer.BirthDate) 
    where // ... 
select customer;  
Error: "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 GetAge(System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression. "

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
var query = from customer in contetx.Customer 
    where (GetAge(customer.BirthDate) > 20 && customer.AccountType == "Saving") ||
          (GetAge(customer.BirthDate) > 40 && customer.AccountType == "Current")
    select customer;
```

You could get around calling `GetAge` twice by using the `let` keyword as Darin did.

```
var query from customer in // ...
    let age = GetAge(customer.BirthDate)
    where // ...
select customer;
```

Comment: is this possible to have two where clauses like this?

Comment: no, it's not. the query should work if you remove the second `where`

Comment: You may get odd results with that where, you need to parenthesis the first and second parts to ensure the or operates on them correctly.

Comment: i get below exception with above query                              "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 GetAge(System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression. "

Comment: no not yet.. but was looking for an option to do something as Dave pointed to use the Extension methods. but really dont know how to use extension methods in the Linq Query. i.e how can i convert my GetAge(DateTime birtdate) static method into extension method and then use it in above query...

Comment: Add an example of your GetAge method as it is at the moment to the original question and I'll take a look, see if I can improve my answer.

Comment: Public static int GetAge(DateTime? birthDay)
{
    if(!birthDay.HasValue)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    int timespan = birthday.Value.TimeSpan;
    int diffTimeSpan = DateTime.Today.TimeSpan - timespan;
    return diffTimeSpan / 365;
}

Here is my GetAge method.